# merging columns from 2 database using sql

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I am working with two databases,primary and secondary. both contains same schema.
now i cant to update column of primary database with the content of same column from secondary database provided the data in secondary database is not NULL.

```
ATTACH "secondary.db" as second;
UPDATE main.table set main.value = coalesce((SELECT value FROM second.table),main.value);
```

but the above code does not work and only the first value of the column from the secondary database is copied to all values in the column in primary database.

For Eg.
primary database:

```
index, value
  1,    45
  2,    56
  3,    23
```

secondary database:

```
index, value
  1,   NULL
  2,   55
  3,   NULL
```

expected result database:

```
index, value
  1,    45
  2,    55
  3,    23
```

Any suggestions?

here you can see what is i am trying:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/845545/1

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What columns link the rows in the two tables?

Comment: edited the question with sample dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a *correlated* subquery:

```
update main.table t
    set main.value = coalesce((select t2.value from second.table t2 where t2.index = t.index),
                              main.value
                             );
```

Or, more efficiently.  Filter the rows and don't use `coalesce()`:

```
update main.table t
    set main.value = (select t2.value from second.table t2 where t2.index = t.index)
    where exists (select 1 from second.table t2 where t2.index = t.index and t2.value is not null)
```

Comment: both suggestion results in filling the primany database column with the 1st value of column from secondary database. :(

Comment: @rkthebest . . . You are doing something wrong.  The corresponding value in the second table is used, not the same value for every row.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/845545/1
have a look here, this is what i am doing

Comment: @rkthebest . . . If you write the query correctly -- as specified in the answer -- it will do what you want: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/845545/3.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!! it completely solves my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've not kept-up with SQLite for a few years, but I think you can now do it with an UPDATE FROM statement like this:

```
UPDATE 
   main
SET 
   main.value = Coalesce (main.value, second.value)
FROM
      main.table
   INNER JOIN
      second.table
   ON main.id = second.id
```

Comment: the priority is the secondary database, if the value exists in secondary database, it should overwrite value in primary database.

How can i use JOIN or WHERE clause in my situation?

Comment: Learning Resource: https://sqlite.org/lang_update.html

Comment: how can i access the second.value?
i tried `Coalesce (main.value, second.table.value)`
but it complains that "no such column"

Comment: @Kuru . . . FYI.  `UPDATE FROM` was introduced in SQLite 3.30, which was released in October 2019.  If you haven't kept up with SQLite, then this syntax was never in SQLite.  In addition, naming the table being updated is incorrect in SQLite.